# Does this healthy primary partition belong to Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning

[image: disk partition details]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

I came back to reinstall Ubuntu since I previously messed up the installation and Ubuntu crashed on shutdown and randomly created log files and all.
Back then I decided to delete all Ubuntu related stuff and reinstall later.
I deleted grub and everything. and also freed up the partition that belonged to Ubuntu (or that's what I believed when I saw the partitions as shown in the image).

I am talking about:
Disk 0 Partition 6 11.44GB
Disk 0 Partition 7 63.56GB

Now I am bit confused and want to know **if it can be safely deleted**. I have doubts being if it's something else necessary for Windows.

For my initial install of Ubuntu I had freed 70GB from Windows, and since my RAM was 12GB I also created swap of 12GB from 70. These memory sizes are almost what the partition sizes are, but I am a new Linux user and don't want to mess things up.

Please do ask for additional details if necessary.

NEWLY ADDED ON REQUEST:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             6045052       0   6045052   0% /dev
tmpfs            1213244    1664   1211580   1% /run
/dev/sdb1        7540960 1906524   5634436  26% /cdrom
/dev/loop0       1820800 1820800         0 100% /rofs
/cow             6066220  299092   5767128   5% /
tmpfs            6066220       0   6066220   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            6066220       0   6066220   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            6066220       0   6066220   0% /tmp
tmpfs            1213244      36   1213208   1% /run/user/999
/dev/loop1         89088   89088         0 100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/loop2         35584   35584         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
/dev/loop3        144384  144384         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
/dev/loop4          2432    2432         0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/180
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL       UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashfs                                                  /rofs
loop1  squashfs                                                  /snap/core/4917
loop2  squashfs                                                  /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
loop3  squashfs                                                  /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
loop4  squashfs                                                  /snap/gnome-calculator/180
loop5  squashfs                                                  /snap/gnome-characters/103
loop6  squashfs                                                  /snap/gnome-logs/37
loop7  squashfs                                                  /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
sda                                                              
├─sda1 vfat     SYSTEM      AA68-D982                            
├─sda2                                                           
├─sda3 ntfs     Windows     CC142E2D142E1ACA                     
├─sda4 ntfs                 0E8A7AE18A7AC52D                     
├─sda5 ntfs     RECOVERY    4C62AB9D62AB89F2                     
├─sda6 swap                 b7d3bb77-4d85-4182-b535-e456c669ae95 [SWAP]
└─sda7 ext4                 1eafcf6b-e0b1-458b-879a-33752037622a 
sdb                                                              
└─sdb1 vfat     UBUNTU 18_0 AA16-AD7D                            /cdrom
sr0                                                              
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -m
NAME     SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
loop0    1.8G root  disk  brw-rw----
loop1   86.9M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop2   34.7M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop3  140.9M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop4    2.3M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop5     13M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop6   14.5M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop7    3.7M root  disk  brw-rw----
sda      1.8T root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda1   260M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda2    16M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda3   1.7T root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda4  1012M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda5  17.2G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda6  11.5G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sda7  63.6G root  disk  brw-rw----
sdb      7.2G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sdb1   7.2G root  disk  brw-rw----
sr0     1024M root  cdrom brw-rw----
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -ls
Model: ATA ST2000LM003 HN-M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  274MB   273MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      274MB   290MB   16.8MB                  Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      290MB   1900GB  1900GB  ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 6      1900GB  1913GB  12.3GB  linux-swap(v1)
 7      1913GB  1981GB  68.2GB  ext4
 4      1981GB  1982GB  1061MB  ntfs                                          hidden, diag
 5      1982GB  2000GB  18.5GB  ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, msftdata


Model: Imation ImationFlashDriv (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 7740MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  7740MB  7739MB  primary  fat32        boot, lba
```

The above code have kinda clarified everything. The 12GB is swap as per the code and I could view the 68GB partition on Ubuntu Live USB and it had Ubuntu files.
So that should be my green flag I guess. Is it not?

FINAL EDIT: Thanks to @sudodus for the code and whatnot. Was helpful. The problem is solved.

Comment: Please boot from your Ubuntu USB pendrive or DVD disk, 'Try Ubuntu' and run the commands `df`and `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo lsblk -m` and `sudo parted -ls` -- Edit your original question to include the output of these commands. Indent each line of the output 4 spaces to render it as 'code'. It makes it easier for us to read, understand and help you :-)

Comment: @sudodus, Thanks a lot for the reply. I've done as you said.

Comment: Yes, that's right :-) You have identified the partitions that you were looking for.

Comment: @sudodus LOL . Thats great. What do I do now . Edit the heading and add [SOLVED]. What's the norm here on AskUbuntu?

Comment: Please don't put `[SOLVED]` in the title of the question. place a green check mark (tick mark) on the left margin of the correct answer. That will help others. If the correct answer is not there, you can write your own answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: @sudodus Since your comment "solved" the problem, may be you could turn that comment to an answer so that OP can accept it.

Comment: @user68186, Done :-)

Answer (score 1):

This way you will get information to identify the [Ubuntu root and swap] partitions:

Please boot from your Ubuntu USB pendrive or DVD disk, 'Try Ubuntu', and run the commands

```
df
sudo lsblk -f
sudo lsblk -m
sudo parted -ls
```

Edit your original question to include the output of these commands. Indent each line of the output 4 spaces to render it as 'code'. It makes the output easier to read.